# How to update an InfoWindowText after the initial click on a marker using Google Maps with Flutter?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, flutter, infowindow

User clicks on the marker on a google map on a flutter app on an android device

As expected infowindow appears

User clicks on infowindow, nothing happens

It was expected to see Title and Snipped updated

I tried with multiple versions and codes.

```
mapController.onInfoWindowTapped.add((marker) {
        _launchURL(data[i]["urlmember"]);
        // options
        print(marker.id.toString());
        print(data[i]["urlmember"]);
        MarkerOptions( infoWindowText: InfoWindowText("counseling","find us on second service"));
);
```

The expected result is for the infowindow to display the new title and snipped

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet is in the example app in the Flutter Google Maps Package (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter) in the file 'place_marker.dart':

```
void _updateSelectedMarker(MarkerOptions changes) {
    controller.updateMarker(_selectedMarker, changes);
  }


  void _onMarkerTapped(Marker marker) {
    if (_selectedMarker != null) {
      _updateSelectedMarker(
        const MarkerOptions(icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker),
      );
    }
    setState(() {
      _selectedMarker = marker;
    });
    _updateSelectedMarker(
      MarkerOptions(
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
          BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I believe that the way you have it set up currently, you click on an info window associated with an pre-existing marker, and that triggers the creation of another marker with no "position" (ie; a LatLng value, which is required for marker objects), but has infoWindow text properties. This would explain why nothing happens when you click on the infoWindow; it's essentially creating a marker and placing it nowhere; which means there wouldn't be anywhere to display the corresponding infoWindow text either.

I believe the logic you are looking to implement is: when a user clicks on the infoWindow, it should trigger an update to the already existing marker. To achieve this, you may implement something similar as the code snippet I shared above, except for using onInfoWindowTapped instead of onMarkerTapped.